# How do I make custom action in my tableView cell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm making a custom action which perform an animation of a GitHub repo. 
Here is my code of VC which has the `TableView`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

 }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    var done1=UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "done", handler: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: indexPath){
        CustomCell.makeanimate(CustomCell)
    }
     return(done1)
}
```

and here is the code of `CustomClass` :

```
func makeanimate() {

    self.checkTest.setOn(true, animated: true)
}
```

I want to call `makeanimate` when I tap `done1`, but I get an error saying **use of instance member 'makeanimate' on type 'customCell'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `makeanimate` is an instance method, but you are calling it as if it was a class method in your code. You need to get a cell instance and then call `makeanimate` via that cell.

Comment: how do I do that ?

Comment: In your "editActionsForRowAt" method, you get a reference to the cell you are interested in using the indexPath value and then call makeanimate as follows:
cell.makeanimate(CustomCell)

Comment: something like `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCellID") as! CustomCell
            cell.makeanimate(CustomCell)` ?

Comment: No, you don't need to dequeue a cell since that cell's already instantiated. You just get the cell for the indexPath using tableview's cellForRow(at:) method.

Comment: I cant get it fixed. Can you write the line of code that I need to implement. Thank you.

Comment: I've given you everything you'd need to fix the issue except write the code for you :) If you can't fix it at this stage, then you might need to do a bit more learning of the Swift basics. If you still can't figure it out after that, please upload the project somewhere and provide a link. I'll take a look in case the issue is not what I (or you) think it is.

Comment: I've implemented the code `let cell=tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell` `cell.makeanimate()`

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what I was talking about. I'm glad that you figured out the answer. My apologies if I seemed as if I was withholding answers but giving all the code sometimes doesn't lead to a good learning experience and `cellForRow` is a method that you will find yourself using over and over if you work with table views.

Comment: Yes, its totally fine..I wont forget the method now :) Thank you.